# What is the difference between a Stack and a Column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to know what are the differences between a `Stack` and a `Column` in Flutter? I know that both widgets are responsiple for stacking Widgets on top of each other I'm a bit confused when to use a `Stack` and when to use a `Column`?

I also know that a `ListView` is scrollable either horizontally or vertically and therefore distinguishes from a `Column` and a `Stack`. But neither the `Stack` nor the `Column` is scrollable.

So what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Stack` widget positions its children relative to the edges of its box. It doesn't necesserily put them on top of each other but it is possible. `Positioned` widget is very useful to position the children in a `Stack`.

`Column` widget displays its children in a vertical array. It splits the available area to multiple areas. `Expanded` widget is a good option to adjust the space ratio between children.

`Row` widget is just a horizontal variant of `Column`.

Answer (score 11):

In a single line difference.

1.Stack can Overlap widgets but columns can't overlap widgets.

if you are coming from an android background then this should be easy to understand
like this.

- the stack is the relative layout and the column is LinearLayout but in the Horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 2):

A stack is a widget used to "stack" (put one widget on top of another), superposing them.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html

On the other hand a column is what it sounds like, it is a widget which allows you to put one widget after another, arranging them vertically.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html